# Is there a way not to award a bounty?

Tags: support

I've offered a bounty on [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/pourquoi-utilise-t-on-un-ordinal-uniquement-pour-le-premier-du-mois) but currently none of the answers seem to deserve it.

My understanding is that if I don't award manually, it will be awarded to the currently highest scored answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [faq](https://french.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started
>   with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If
>   there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to
>   anyone.
>
> [...]
>
> In any case, you will always give up the amount of reputation
>   specified in the bounty, so if you start a bounty, be sure to follow
>   up and award your bounty to the best answer!

So, as it stands now, it seems that your bounty will just fall into nothingness.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not awarded the bounty at the end of the grace period (24 hours after the bounty ends), then the highest-voted eligible answer, if any, receives half the amount. An answer is eligible if it was posted during the bounty period (neither before you offered the bounty nor during the grace period), and if it had at least two upvotes by the end of the bounty period. If there are several eligible answers, the one with the highest score is chosen, and in case of a tie the oldest answer is chosen.

At this moment, [Axioplase's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/pourquoi-utilise-t-on-un-ordinal-uniquement-pour-le-premier-du-mois/1569#1569) might become eligible, if it receives two upvotes. If it doesn't, and no one else posts an answer, then the bounty will vanish into thin air unless you award it manually.